# Affine Subspaces $\mathbf{a} + V = \{ \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{w} : \mathbf{w} \in V\}$: Adding/Subtracting Non-Set Objects (Vector Elements) from Sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, notation, convex-optimization

The following article seems to show non-set objects (in this case, vectors) being subtracted from sets:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_subspaces_and_parallelism

I’m wondering what’s going on here, since, as far as I’ve learned, this is not a valid mathematical operation?

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: It's commonly used notation, and moreover, the author explicitly _defines_ it. It's essentially _coset_ notation, as used in Group Theory.

Comment: @quasi Ok, thanks for the clarification. I don't understand why the title was edited, since what I wrote was precisely what was written in the Wikipedia article. Now it is entirely different ...

Comment: I didn't make the edit, but if you want, you can edit it again so as to incorporate the actual notation you were asking about.

Comment: @quasi Yes. In the interest of consistency, I think that's a good idea, since my post refers to the article itself.